# Where can I find a worldwide list of IATA cities with airports?

Tags: c#, service

I am writing an app to display flights between cities and want to include a combo with cities/countries with airports for the person to select. Then I call a GDS web service to display flight info. But the GDS does not supply worldwide IATA cities/airports with one call. Does anyone know of a suitable source where I can obtain this information to put it in an asp combo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=IATA+city+list) found me several links to what you are looking for:

- http://www.photius.com/wfb2001/airport_codes_alpha.html
- http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/IATA_Codes/airport_code_list.htm
- http://www.airport-technology.com/codes/

and probably definitive, but you have to pay for it:

- http://www.iata.org/ps/publications/ccd.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can get this kind of data for free from OpenFlights project (AGPL): http://openflights.org/data.html