# Airport codes - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on an application that needs to detect the user's location.

I need to extract the user's country and city codes.

I was able to get the country code using a placemark in `locationManager: didUpdateToLocation: fromLocation:` as follows:

```
CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        MKPlacemark * mark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSString * code = mark.countryCode;

        NSLog(@"country code: %@", code);

    }];
```

So, is there any solution that helps me find an [IATA 3-Letter Code](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/IATA_Codes/IATA_Code_D.htm) for the user's city ?

Comment: I suppose the only solution is using an available external database to connect/match your position to an IATA. This Thread mentions available services: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787782/where-can-i-find-a-worldwide-list-of-iata-cities-with-airports

Here is another DB you could use http://www.partow.net/miscellaneous/airportdatabase/, unfortunately not a web service.

Comment: Thank you @Ben-G, I will be using the global airport database.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the database available at OpenFlights: http://openflights.org/data.html (which @Ben-G linked indirectly).

There is a somewhat 'web service' as a form: http://openflights.org/html/apsearch but I think that given the size of the database (about 9200 entries) it is actually better to import it in the app and query it directly, specially if you are going to query a lot (more queries... more traffic if using a web service, and so more delay and decreased user experience, etc).

Though I wonder why you wouldn't calculate a circle given the user's position and then query the database for any airport within some specific radius. That will give you all airports in the whereabouts and obviously the cities and the country. Getting the airport code(s) given the user's city might give you nothing if the city mainly served by an airport doesn't correspond to the city of the user's location.